# Insert into table with multiple joins under a unique condition based off time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an insert statment that incorporates multiple joins. However, the last join (table ItemMulitplers) doesnt really have anything "tied" to the other tables. They are just multipliers in this table with no unique identification or connection with others. the only thing is a timestamp from this table.

I have 5 rows in this table and my script is taking all five rows. I need it to select only one and to base it off of the closest time from the table called ItemsProduced. They get executed at the same time but not on the same millisecond level. any help is most appreciated thank you

```
insert into KLNUser.dbo.ItemLookup  (ItemNumber, Cases, [Description], [Type], Wic, Elc,    totalelc,  Shift, [TimeStamp])


    select  a.ItemNumber, b.CaseCount,b.ItemDescription, b.DivisionCode, b.WorkCenter, b.LaborPerCase, a.CaseCount* b.LaborPerCase* c.IaCoPc, a.shift, a.TimeStamp from ItemsProduced a 

       inner join MasterItemList b on a.ItemNumber = b.itemnumber
       inner join ItemMultipliers c on c.MultiplyTimeStamp <=a.Timestamp Interval 1        seconds


    where not exists (select *  from ItemLookup where ItemNumber = a.ItemNumber and Cases = b.CaseCount and [TimeStamp] = a.TimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is with `cross apply`:

```
select  a.ItemNumber, b.CaseCount,b.ItemDescription, b.DivisionCode, b.WorkCenter, b.LaborPerCase, a.CaseCount* b.LaborPerCase* c.IaCoPc, a.shift, a.TimeStamp
from ItemsProduced a inner join
     MasterItemList b
     on a.ItemNumber = b.itemnumber cross apply
     (select top 1 *
      from ItemMultipliers c
      where c.MultiplyTimeStamp < a.Timestamp
      order by c.MultiplyTimeStamp desc
     ) c
where not exists (select *  from ItemLookup where ItemNumber = a.ItemNumber and Cases = b.CaseCount and [TimeStamp] = a.TimeStamp)
```